# Why is UserAuthName with @ symbol not added to the jwt token in ServiceStack JwtAuthProvider?

Tags: jwt, servicestack

In method CreateJwtPayload() in JwtAuthProvider.cs (https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/45108614b77c37185e3fe471ad49a462b825354c/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/Auth/JwtAuthProvider.cs#L361) are usernames with "@" symbol not setted to the payload "preferred_username".

Code snippet:

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(session.UserName))
        jwtPayload["preferred_username"] = session.UserName;
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(session.UserAuthName) && !session.UserAuthName.Contains("@"))
        jwtPayload["preferred_username"] = session.UserAuthName;
```

Usernames in our system may contain "@" symbol, and are now not added the payload "preferred_username".

Is there a reason why UserAuthName "@" is not added to the payload in this JswAuthProvider of ServiceStack?

Answer (score 1):

Usernames with a `@` is what's used to determine whether a Username is an email in ServiceStack.

You can use the `CreatePayloadFilter` to [modify the JWT payload](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#jwt-payload) to populate  it yourself.

Comment: The question is not what the `@` is for, but the reason why `preferred_username` is not set when the value contains a `@`

Comment: @AlbertVanHalen the answer is still because it’s considered to be an email

Comment: Looking at the code snippet above, when the `UserName` property in the session object contains a `@`, the `preferred_username` property is set without any condition

Comment: @AlbertVanHalen Sessions are for internal usage, it's not representative of how it should be included in a JWT which is kept as minimal to reduce cookie payload of each request. In this case the User doesn't have a Username and their Email's already included.

Comment: @Mythz, in our system users can have an email address as a username, but this is a separate field than their actual email address

Comment: @RobinBouwmeester Right, didn't think this would be a use-case, you can use the filter now to add it to the JWT, I'll also remove the restriction so it won't be needed om the next version